# How to run ./configure from another ./configure

Tags: bash, unix, autotools, configure

I was wondering is it possible to run a configure script from another one? What I have is the situation where  my own project uses autotools for config and make. So before any build a configure script is ran (as usual). But now I want to add another lib to my project which also uses the same build principle (It is necessary to run configure script before building a project). So instead of making my future users run two configure scripts, is there a way to automate this. (but without using a shell script - bash, perl, etc.)

Can this be done and if so, how??

Comment: Via the [`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Subdirectories) macro.

Comment: Best practice is to require the user to provide the dependency.   Your project requires the library, and if the user wants to build your project from source they must first build the library.  If you want to minimize the work the user needs to do, provide an rpm, deb, and/or pkg.  The autotools are not a package management system, and attempting to use them as such is a mistake.